# How can you tell if your Android app is using Kotlin or Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How can you tell if your Android app is using Kotlin or Java in Android Studio?

I am extremely new to Android app creation still.

I have looked at the code, but I am enough of a novice that it is hard to tell for sure.

I tried Googling this question and all that seems to come up is articles about which to use, java or Kotlin.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just look for some of the common syntax differences: Java requires a semicolon at the end of most statements, kotlin does not. Kotlin has a `val` keyword for declarations, Java does not (AFAIK). Kotlin uses `?` at the end of type names to mark a nullable type, Java does not.

Answer (score 5):

Just Check your Activity Name

For Java App

```
MainActivity.java -> (.java) -> It's Java App
```

For Kotlin App

```
MainActivity.kt -> (.kt) -> It's Kotlin App
```

Comment: I'm ignorant on this topic, so bear with me. My project doesn't have a MainActivity, but in the AndroidManifest.xml there's an `<activity ...` with 
```<intent-filter>
<action ... .action.MAIN"/>
<category... .category.LAUNCHER"/>
```
The `android:name` seems to point to a `.kt` file so I guess it's Kotlin.

Comment: @oliversissonyes it's a Kotlin project

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin files have extensions `.kt`, Java ones `.java`. besides that easiest way for distinguishing would be to check semicolons `;` at the end of some/most of lines in Java, while in Kotlin they aren't required. another way: in Kotlin you will find `val` and `var` keywords, commonly used and not present in Java code

if you don't know how to distinguish two languages then probably you should start some coding learning, not opening some foreign project

Answer (score 0):

1. Check File Extensions:

Kotlin files typically have the extension .kt.
Java files typically have the extension .java.
Look in your project's source code directory for files with these extensions.

2. View Project Structure:

In Android Studio, you can view the project structure in the "Project" view on the left side of the IDE.
Kotlin files are usually located in the src/main/kotlin directory.
Java files are usually located in the src/main/java directory.

3. Check Build Files:

Open the build.gradle files in your project.
If you see dependencies like implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7', it indicates Kotlin usage.
If you see dependencies like implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle', it indicates a Java project.

4. Check Language Features:

Open a source code file (.kt or .java) and look for language-specific features.
Kotlin has certain features like val for read-only properties, extension functions, etc., that are not present in Java.